# disable package key-binding override in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, perforce

This seems like some basic Emacs configuration issue that I do not understand.

I have Emacs 24.3 preinstalled on site. In a Verilog file, pressing M-s is bound to p4-current-file "edit" (Perforce operation), likewise M-e is bound to p4-current-file "sync". All is well.
The problem is in a VHDL file, M-s does the same, but M-e is bound to "vhdl-end-of-statement". I would like it to do "p4 edit" like in Verilog.

Seems that vhdl-mode is overriding the M-e key function, and I cannot not find how to change this permanently. If I do local-unset-key and unset M-e, I get the desired result, M-e does p4 edit, but when I restart Emacs M-e does "vhdl-end-of-statement" again.

How can I change M-e to do "p4 edit" permanently? I'm not fluent in Lisp, but will be happy to get instructions how to change this.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that in many major modes, `M-e` will be set to some equivalent to end of statement / end of sentence. You might find it easier in the log run to rebind your perforce bindings.

Comment: Look in the VHDL mode code for the keymap that it uses - it is likely `vhdl-mode-map`. Define `M-e` in that keymap to be the command you want. If necessary (e.g., if the mode map is not defined at the outset), you can put that `define-key` sexp on the mode hook, so that it takes effect whenever the mode is turned on.

Comment: MrBones, thanks for that suggestion, I'll do that, it's also the simplest solution to change the perforce bindings (see below)

Comment: Drew, thanks for your help. I can't seem to get to "vhdl-mode-map", can you please give detailed instructions? In the emacs install dir there is a file emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes/vhdl-mode.elc,probably that is where vhdl bindings are defined. It is public so I can't change it but perhaps I can copy the vhdl-mode definitions to a local file, have emacs read in the definitions from a local file which I can modify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove an over-riding binding from a mode keymap, so that Emacs will fall back to what it would usually use, you would normally do something like this:

```el
(eval-after-load "vhdl-mode"
  '(progn
    (define-key vhdl-mode-map (kbd "M-e") nil) ;; unbind M-e
    (define-key vhdl-mode-map (kbd "M-a") nil))) ;; unbind M-a
```

As MrBones comments, though, these are not very desirable custom bindings. Both <kbd>M-s</kbd> and <kbd>M-e</kbd> have standard uses in Emacs (the former is normally a prefix binding which a bunch of useful things hang off), and if possible you should consider moving those bindings to other keys.

(My impression is that the "preinstalled on site" version had these bindings already in place, though? In which case that's more a note for whoever maintains that...)

Comment: Thanks phils, the perforce bindings are global-set-key in my .emacs file, I can edit those. I decided to follow your and MrBones' advice, I changed the perforce bindings to ESC M-e, ESC M-s, etc. eval-after-load looks useful, saved for a rainy day :-). Following my comment to Drew, and to enhance my understanding, how can I modify vhdl-mode-map? (vhdl-mode.elc)

Comment: You use the technique I've shown above to modify the bindings in `vhdl-mode-map`, which is the keymap for `vhdl-mode`. `eval-after-load` ensures that your code does not try to modify the keymap before it exists. I've added a `progn` wrapper and an extra example to the code, to show how to do multiple things. If you wished to *bind* a key to some command in that keymap, you would simply replace `nil` with `'some-command`.